# how to rewrite and add a new parameter in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want rewrite a url to another using mod_rewrite.. but i want to preserve the query parameters and and POST data even after the rewrite.
And i want to add a new parameter to the url when rewriting it...
For example

This ->  http://example.com/test/?user=234343

To -> http://example.com/othertest/user=234343&new_param=CUSTOM_VALUE    //i'll just type this value in the .htaccess file

It will be very helpful if anyone could show me an example how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try:

```
RewriteRule     ^test/?user=([0-9]+)$ /othertest/user/$1&new_param=CUSTOM_VALUE [L]
```

Comment: actually it should handle any parameter that will be in the url.. i included user just as an example

Comment: OK, i did not realize that. Is "/test" to "/othertest" given as fixed requirement, or is that also just an example?

Comment: well "/test" to "/othertest" can be fixed.. so i have to add many rewrite rules for my requirements.